# image loading using url in android

Tags: android, android-layout, url, android-imageview

i was tring to load image using url.a single url is working properly. but i need to add a few more images to this page.i need to add this image s to a list view.pls tell me how can i add a string array to this code.

```
import java.io.IOException;

import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.apache.http.protocol.HTTP;
import org.apache.http.util.EntityUtils;
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class FareCrd extends Activity {



    String image_url="http://movito.nervov.com/img/ace-hd.png";
    String[] mString ={"http://movito.nervov.com/img/ace-hd.png",
            "http://movito.nervov.com/img/Movito_Logo_M.png"};

JSONArray jsonary;

    ListView list;
    private Activity activity;
    private String[] data;
    private static View inflater=null;
    //private String[] mStrings={"http://movito.nervov.com/img/ace-hd.png"};

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_fare_crd);
        list=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.farelist);



        new ServConn().execute(); 



    }


private void parsedata(String data){
    //System.out.println(data);

        try {
            JSONObject json = new JSONObject(data);

            jsonary = json.getJSONArray("data");


            ListView list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.farelist);

            list.setAdapter(new DriverOrderList(getApplicationContext(),
                    R.layout.farecrd, new JSONObject[jsonary.length()]));



        } catch (JSONException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


    }

private class DriverOrderList extends ArrayAdapter<JSONObject> {

    int listViewResource;


    public DriverOrderList(Context context, int resource, JSONObject[] s) {
        super(context, resource, s);
        listViewResource = resource;


    }
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        View row = ((LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE)).inflate(listViewResource, parent, false);
        ImageLoader imgLoader = new ImageLoader(getApplicationContext());   
        JSONObject rowdata = new JSONObject();
        int loader = R.drawable.stub;


        try {


            rowdata = jsonary.getJSONObject(position);
            System.out.println(rowdata);

             ImageLoader imgLoader1 = new ImageLoader(getApplicationContext());
        ImageView img=(ImageView) row.findViewById(R.id.imgid);



        imgLoader.DisplayImage(image_url, loader, img);


        TextView nameTxt = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.truckname);         
        TextView idTxt = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.id);



        TextView minrttv =(TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.minimumRate);
        TextView kmrttxt =(TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.kilometerRate);
        TextView mindurtv=(TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.minimumDuration);
        TextView freewatintim = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.freeWaitingTime);
        TextView minuterttxt =(TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.minuteRate);
        TextView watingchrttv =(TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.waitingCharge);

        double freewt=(Double) rowdata.get("freeWaitingTime");
        double kmratetxt=(Double) rowdata.get("kilometerRate");
        double mindurtxt=(Double) rowdata.get("minimumDuration");
        double mindur= mindurtxt/60;
        double minkmrttxt=(Double) rowdata.get("minimumKilometer");     
        double minrttxt=(Double) rowdata.get("minimumRate");
        double mintrate=(Double) rowdata.get("minuteRate");
        double minutrat=mintrate/60;
        double watingchrtxt=(Double) rowdata.get("waitingCharge");
        double waitchgunittxt=(Double) rowdata.get("waitingChargeUnit");



            nameTxt.setText(rowdata.getString("truckModel"));
            minrttv.setText("Rs."+minrttxt+" /-");
            kmrttxt.setText("Rs."+kmratetxt+"/km after "+minkmrttxt+"km");
            mindurtv.setText("first"+mindur+"hr and "+minkmrttxt+"km");
            //minuterttxt.setText(minutrat+"/-");
            freewatintim.setText("first "+freewt+"min free");
            watingchrttv.setText("RS"+watingchrtxt+"after every "+waitchgunittxt+"min");

        }   
         catch (JSONException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }



         return row;
    }

}



private class ServConn extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        System.out.println("do in backgrnd");
        HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpGet httpget = new HttpGet("http://movito.nervov.com/v1/trucks/miniTruckCategories");

        httpget.setHeader(HTTP.CONTENT_TYPE, "application/json");
        String replyString = "";

        try {

            HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httpget);
            replyString = EntityUtils.toString(response
                    .getEntity());



        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {

        System.out.println("ex: " + e);
        } catch (IOException e) {

        System.out.println("e: " + e);
        }


    return replyString;

}

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onPostExecute(result);

        System.out.println(result);
        result = "{\"data\":"+result+"}";


        parsedata(result);

    }
     @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {}

        @Override
        protected void onProgressUpdate(Void... values) {}
}



}
```

Comment: If you have mString why do you still need image_url?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Lazy load of images in ListView](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/541966/lazy-load-of-images-in-listview)

Answer (score 0):

try this code I am using **Picasso** library to populate `ImageView`,

if you are using android studio add this library using following code into your gradle file

```
compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
```

use following code,

It is complete example of how you can make a custom `ListView`, I didn't include code where you have to get he **JSON** data from `WebService` as i didn't want to make the code complicated, I will write a separate code where i will show how to read the data you are interested in.

> XML

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">


    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/CustomListViewActivity_listView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
</LinearLayout>
```

> single_item.xml layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/single_item_textView"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="4dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.5"
        android:text="New Text" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/single_item_imageView"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_margin="4dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.5" />
</LinearLayout>
```

> Code

```
public class CustomListViewActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_custom_list_view);


        ArrayList<SingleItem> singleItems = new ArrayList<>();
        singleItems.add(new SingleItem("http://movito.nervov.com/img/ace-hd.png","first Text"));
        singleItems.add(new SingleItem("http://movito.nervov.com/img/Movito_Logo_M.png","Second Text"));
        singleItems.add(new SingleItem("http://movito.nervov.com/img/ace-hd.png","third Text"));
        singleItems.add(new SingleItem("http://movito.nervov.com/img/Movito_Logo_M.png","fourth Text"));

        ListView listView = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.CustomListViewActivity_listView);
        MyAdapter adapter = new MyAdapter(getApplicationContext(), R.layout.single_item,singleItems);
        listView.setAdapter(adapter);


    }

    private class MyAdapter extends ArrayAdapter {

        private ArrayList<SingleItem> singleItems;
        private LayoutInflater layoutInflater;
        private Context context;
        private View single_View;

        public MyAdapter(Context context, int resource, ArrayList<SingleItem> singleItems) {
            super(context, resource, singleItems);
            this.context = context;
            this.singleItems = singleItems;
            layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(this.context);
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            View row = convertView;
            ViewHolder holder = null;

            if (row == null) {
                row = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.single_item, parent, false);

                holder = new ViewHolder();
                holder.textView = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.single_item_textView);
                holder.imageView = (ImageView) row.findViewById(R.id.single_item_imageView);
                row.setTag(holder);
            } else {
                holder = (ViewHolder) row.getTag();
            }

            final SingleItem singleItem = singleItems.get(position);
            holder.textView.setText("" + singleItem.getText());
            Picasso.with(context).load(""+singleItem.getUrl()).into(holder.imageView);

            return row;
        }

        private class ViewHolder {
            // Instance Variable (state or data)
            TextView textView;
            ImageView imageView;
        }
    }

    public class SingleItem {

        private String url;

        private String text;

        public SingleItem() {
        }

        public SingleItem(String url, String text) {
            this.url = url;
            this.text = text;
        }

        public String getUrl() {
            return url;
        }

        public void setUrl(String url) {
            this.url = url;
        }

        public String getText() {
            return text;
        }

        public void setText(String text) {
            this.text = text;
        }
    }
}
```

> Output

As you will see the loading the images from the URL provided to the appropriate `ImageView` is taken care by **Picasso**, do make sure you add the permission for the internet in the `AndroidManifest.xml`

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try to use Glide libreries instead od picasso .It might help full for you.Please look at following link which might help you out.
http://inthecheesefactory.com/blog/get-to-know-glide-recommended-by-google/en