# java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException.....CompanyAdpater.getview

Tags: android, listview, android-arrayadapter, indexoutofboundsexception

I am new to Android. I am getting 391 items in my listview. All is working fine till 390 and it is visible but when i scroll down to see the last items, my app crashes. Help me Guys. Thank you in advance.

MainActivity:

```
public class Companies extends Activity {

ListView list_com;
String value[];
String c_city, c_state;
String company, address, phone, email, website;
CompanyAdapter com_ad;
ProgressDialog pDialog;
EditText ed_search;
String com_name1[];
String com_name, com_id, city, state, city1[], state1[], com_id1[];

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_companies);
    list_com = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list_company);
    //ed_search = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.ed_search);

    new AttemptCompany().execute();
    }
    class AttemptCompany extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

    /**
     * Before starting background thread Show Progress Dialog
     * */

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(Companies.this);
        pDialog.setMessage("Loading....");
        pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
        pDialog.setCancelable(false);
        pDialog.show();
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... args) {
        // Check for success tag

        try {
            // Building Parameters
            ArrayList<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();

            Parser parser = new Parser();
            JSONObject json = parser.getJSONFromUrl(
                    "http://.....",
                    nameValuePairs);

            Log.d("Login attempt", json.toString());

            int udata = json.getInt("udata");
            if (udata == 1) {
                city = json.getString("city");
                state = json.getString("state");
                city1 = city.split(",");
                state1 = state.split(",");

                JSONArray udata1 = json.getJSONArray("result");
                for (int i = 0; i < udata1.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject json1 = (JSONObject) udata1.get(i);
                    if (i == 0) {
                        com_name = (i + 1) + ". "
                                + json1.getString("company") + ",";
                        com_id = json1.getString("id") + ",";
                    } else {
                        com_name += (i + 1) + ". "
                                + json1.getString("company") + ",";
                        com_id += json1.getString("id") + ",";
                    }
                }

                com_name1 = com_name.split(",");
                com_id1 = com_id.split(",");

                return null;
            }

            if (udata == 0) {
                /*
                 * Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "No data found",
                 * Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                 */
                return "No data found";
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            Log.e("Exception", "" + e.toString());
            return "No data found";
        }

        return null;

    }

    /**
     * After completing background task Dismiss the progress dialog
     * **/
    protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
        // dismiss the dialog once product deleted
        pDialog.dismiss();
        if (file_url != null) {
            Toast.makeText(Companies.this, file_url, Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .show();
        }

        else {

            Log.e("log_tag", "Hello");
            com_ad = new CompanyAdapter(Companies.this, com_name1, city1,state1);
            list_com.setAdapter(com_ad);
            list_com.setTextFilterEnabled(true);
        }

    }

}
}
```

Adapter:

```
public class CompanyAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {
String companyname[];
String city[];
String state[];
Context context;

TextView tv_city, tv_company, tv_state;

public CompanyAdapter(Context context, String[] companyname, String[] city,
        String[] state) {
    super(context, R.layout.listview, companyname);
    this.context = context;
    this.city = city;
    this.state = state;
    this.companyname = companyname;

}

@SuppressLint("ViewHolder")
public View getView(final int positon, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
            .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.companylist, parent, false);

    tv_company = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.company_name1);
    tv_city = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.cityList);
    tv_state = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.stateList);

    tv_company.setText(companyname[positon]);
    tv_city.setText(city[positon]);
    tv_state.setText(state[positon]);

    return rowView;

}

}
```

Company.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="#fddcaa"
android:orientation="vertical"
tools:context="${packageName}.${activityClass}" >

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="45dp"
    android:background="@drawable/bg_color_image"
    android:text="Companies Name"
    android:textSize="20sp"
    android:textStyle="bold" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="1dp"
    android:background="#000" />
<ListView
    android:id="@+id/list_company"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:divider="#000"
    android:dividerHeight="1dp" >
</ListView>

</LinearLayout>
```

Adapter XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"    
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="60dp"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:background="#fddcaa"
android:weightSum="1" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/company_name1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight=".60"
    android:gravity="top"
    android:text="S.No"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:paddingLeft="10dp"
    android:textColor="#000"
    android:textSize="16sp" />

  <LinearLayout 
   android:layout_width="fill_parent"
   android:layout_height="0dp"
   android:orientation="horizontal"
   android:layout_weight=".3"
   android:weightSum="2">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/cityList"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:text="Name"
     android:paddingLeft="5dp"
    android:textColor="#000"
    android:textSize="14sp" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/stateList"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
     android:paddingLeft="5dp"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:text="D.O.B"
    android:textColor="#000"
    android:textSize="14sp" />
</LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

LogCat:

```
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=392; index=392
01-07 11:31:25.576: E/AndroidRuntime(13317):    at com.company.android.CompanyAdapter.getView(CompanyAdapter.java:41)
01-07 11:31:25.576: E/AndroidRuntime(13317):    at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:2347)
01-07 11:31:25.576: E/AndroidRuntime(13317):    at android.widget.ListView.makeAndAddView(ListView.java:1864)
01-07 11:31:25.576: E/AndroidRuntime(13317):    at android.widget.ListView.fillDown(ListView.java:698)
01-07 11:31:25.576: E/AndroidRuntime(13317):    at android.widget.ListView.fillGap(ListView.java:662)
```

Comment: Can you post your log quick? Of your crash

Comment: check if one of company city or state is not missing a item ? can you post logcat too, or the line at which this exception is fired ?

Comment: wait i am posting my log

Comment: Can you post the exception please

Comment: can you check how many item you had in each of your array companyname, city and state?

Comment: waiting for Logcat Log . so we are finding exact error.

Comment: @AndroidLover, you need to think more like **OOP** and start making object of data type. Can't always depend on primitive types

Comment: @AndroidLover how many items are there in the `ListView`?

Comment: @AndroidLover, here is complete example of what you can do, it is crude but is made for understanding http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34608933/image-loading-using-url-in-android/34618061#34618061

Comment: @KNeerajLal 391 items

Comment: i guess you had 392 item in your companyname array while your city or state array is less than 392 thats why you get arrayindexoutof bound

Comment: @AndroidLover show the xml of `companylist`.

Comment: @AndroidLover, this example tells how to populate attaylist from json.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34626059/json-data-into-spinner-based-on-selection/34633223#34633223

Comment: What you are passing in getCount?

Comment: Refer this:- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2596547/arrayindexoutofboundsexception-with-custom-android-adapter-for-multiple-views-in

Comment: @AndroidLover show the xml of `companylist`, the xml for single item.

Comment: @KNeerajLal check the updated question

Comment: @PranavBhatt I am using arrayadapter not baseadapter...

Comment: @AndroidLover set `android:layout_height` to `match_parent`.

Comment: What is line 41 in CompanyAdapter.java?

Comment: @DanielNugent Line number 42--> tv_city.setText(city[positon]);

Comment: @AndroidLover did setting `android:layout_height` to `match parent` change anything?

Comment: Add log statements to log `companyname.length` and `city.length` and `state.length` right before line 41.

Comment: @DanielNugent @K neeraj Let me check

Comment: i think one of the arrays are shorter than others, so one of the `setText()` lines in the adapter is making the crash, check line 41, which array is related to, a good hint is to log all arrays length at `doInbackground()` once download and parse completes, put the logging lines just before the `return null;` line

Comment: @DanielNugent it's only showing companyname.length=394 but not the city.length & state.length

Comment: @Yazan I think you are right my tv_city.setText(city[positon]); is the calprit for the crash...but i don't have any solution to resolve it.

Comment: The problem is in your JSON parsing.  Log `city1.length` and `state1.lenght`, and log the `city` and `state` strings before you call split() on them.

Comment: if data retried is not guaranteed, you will have to check array length against position, `if(city.length>position){txtCity.setText(city[position]);}else{txtCity.setText("N/A");}`

Comment: @Yazan thanks! it solved my problem...

Answer (score 0):

Replace with,

```
public View getView(final int positon, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    if (city.length <= position)
         return null;

    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
            .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.companylist, parent, false);

    tv_company = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.company_name1);
    tv_city = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.cityList);
    tv_state = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.stateList);

    tv_company.setText(companyname[positon]);
    tv_city.setText(city[positon]);
    tv_state.setText(state[positon]);

    return rowView;

}
```